# Proving that if $X_n-x_n\to0$, $X_n-y_n\to0$ in probability then $x_n- y_n\to0$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

How to prove that if $X_n-x_n\to0$,  $X_n-y_n\to0$ in probability then $x_n- y_n\to0$ where $\{x_n\}, \{y_n\}$ are real sequences?

Answer (score 1):

Well, note that $\mathbb{P}(|x_n-y_n|\geq \varepsilon)\in \{0,1\}$ for each $n$ each $\varepsilon>0$. Now, let $\varepsilon>0$ be given and note that

$$\mathbb{P}(|x_n-y_n|\geq \varepsilon)\leq \mathbb{P}(|X_n-x_n|\geq \varepsilon/2)+\mathbb{P}(|X_n-y_n|\geq \varepsilon/2),$$

and the right hand side goes to $0$ by assumption. By the above observation, we get that $|x_n-y_n|< \varepsilon$ for $n$ sufficiently large.

Since $\varepsilon>0$ was arbitrary, this proves that $x_n-y_n\to 0$.

Comment: Where does the inequality of the probabilities come from? Does it follow from the triangle inequality?

Comment: Yes. Since $|x_n-y_n|\leq |x_n-X_n|+|y_n-Y_n|$. So $(|x_n-y_n|\geq \varepsilon)\subseteq (|X_n-x|\geq \varepsilon/2)\cup (|Y_n-y|\geq \varepsilon/2)$. Note that I'd forgotten a factor of $1/2$.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou  Why does the probability need to be $0$ or $1$ is it because $x_n$, $y_n$ are real numbers?

Comment: Yes. It's because $x_n$ and $y_n$ aren't random.

Answer (score 0):

Fix a subsequence $(n_{k})$, some further subsequence $(n_{k_{l}})$ is such that $X_{n_{k_{l}}}(\omega)-x_{n_{k_{l}}}, X_{n_{k_{l}}}(\omega)-y_{n_{k_{l}}}\rightarrow 0$ almost surely, now $x_{n_{k_{l}}}-y_{n_{k_{l}}}\rightarrow 0$. The arbitrariness of the subsequences $(n_{k})$ shows that $x_{n}-y_{n}\rightarrow 0$.

Answer (score 0):

If you can operate properties of convergence in probability then 
$$
y_n-x_n= X_n-y_n - (X_n-x_n) \to 0-0=0
$$
in probability.